# How to rename/alias rabl nodes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a Rails 3.2.14 app and I am using Rabl for outputting API data.
I want to change the names of the root node (notifications) and object node (notification) for the output below. How can I do that?

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "notifications": [
    {
      "notification": {
        "id": 2,
        "subject": "Testing",
        "body": "Testing",
        "created_at": "16 Jan 2014 14:22",
        "conversation": 2,
        "sender_id": 5,
        "sender_name": "Mike Swanson"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The show.rabl file:

```
object false
node(:total) { @output.count }
child(@output) { extends 'api/v1/shared/conversation_rich' }
```

The conversation_rich file:

```
attributes :id, :subject, :body

node(:created_at) { |message| message.created_at.strftime("%e %b %Y %H:%M") }
node(:conversation) { |message| message.conversation.id }
node(:sender_id) { |message| message.sender.id }
node(:sender_name) { |message| message.sender.fullname }
```

**Update**

Turns out it was extremely simple. Just add => :messages:

```
child(@output => :messages) { extends 'api/v1/shared/conversation_rich' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was extremely simple. Just add => :messages:

```
child(@output => :messages) { extends 'api/v1/shared/conversation_rich' }
```